# Why does catch in a method handling an Action truncate the stack trace?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

Consider this small program. Ignore, if you will, the generic catch, I've kept it brief to try and illustrate the point:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Try(Fail);
}

private static void Fail()
{
    var x = ((string)null).Clone();
}

private static void Try(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);                
    }
}
```

When run, the following (with some of the path info removed) is produced:

```
at Scratch.Program.Fail() in Program.cs:line 27
at Scratch.Program.Try(Action action) in Program.cs:line 34
```

My question is - why does the stack trace of the exception stop unwinding the method chain at the `Try()` method? I would expect it to unwind past that to the `Main()` method.

I haven't been able to find any documentation about what it is that stops exception unwinding going past the `Try()` - so I'd like to understand this.

Comment: You are catching the exception in `Try()`, if you caught it in `Main()` then that's where the stack trace would end.

Comment: This doesn't actually have anything to do with `Action`, it happens even if you just have `Try` call `Fail` directly: http://ideone.com/X9JQFS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Exception.Stacktrace`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/950d763693dd32d3.html) calls `GetStackTrace` which in the end will call
`new StackTrace(this /* exception object */, true)`. When used with these parameters the stack trace will be evaluated for the point of the exception until the current method. You can check that yourself when adding

```
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(new StackTrace());
    Debug.WriteLine(new StackTrace(exc, true));          
}
```

The second version is the stacktrace returned by `exc.StackTrace`, the first is the full stacktrace from the current method to the entry point or thread start.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it answers the question without leaving me with any further questions - many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
try
{
    action();
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(exc.StackTrace);                
}
```

catches your exception inside `Try`, and doesn't propagate upwards to unwind the callstack, it simply swallows the exception. Therefor, you don't see `Main` as part of your stacktrace. If you want to see `Main`, leave the `catch` to your `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Try(Fail);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

And now you see:

> at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Fail() in
>   C:\Users\Yuval\documents\visual studio
>   14\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 25
>   at ConsoleApplication2.Program.Try(Action action) in
>   C:\Users\Yuval\documents\visual studio
>   14\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 30
>   at **ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args)** in
>   C:\Users\Yuval\documents\visual studio
>   14\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 15