# C# Why Exception.StackTrace doesn't contain full stacktrace?

Tags: c#, exception, architecture

I read from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The StackTrace property returns the frames of the call stack that originate at the location where the exception was thrown

The quote isn't clear to me, so let's see example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            A();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("second catch. Stacktrace: {0}", e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
    public static void A()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("first catch. Stacktrace: {0}", e.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Output: (hidden 'in' chunks)

```
first catch. Stacktrace:    
   at TestExceptions.Program.A()
second catch. Stacktrace:    
   at TestExceptions.Program.A()
   at TestExceptions.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Exception.StackTrace in first catch block doesn't contain full stack trace, including 'Main' method call.
More generally, Exception.StackTrace contains only stack frames between catching block and throwing place.

Does anybody know, why was choosen such decision? Due to performance issues, or there are some other problems?

Update:

question is different from [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26973669/why-does-catch-in-a-method-handling-an-action-truncate-the-stack-trace). I would like to know why choosen decision that exception.StackTrace would return part of stack.

Comment: Isn't `exception.StackTrace` usually only needed to pinpoint (and/or log) the origin of a known exception inside a try/catch? So in very deep hierarchies, you don't fill up the log with "unnecessary" information. If the exception occurs outside a try/catch, the application would terminate with the complete stacktrace. -- I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but with simply `var stacktrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();` you can get the complete stacktrace at that point anywhere you want.

Comment: Corak, I think that if we want to log place of occured exception, we need to log full stack, because logging part of stack maybe non informative (catching method can be called from 10 other methods, but logged parts of stacktraces would identical)

Comment: Yes, I know about methods that provide full stack trace, such as new StackTrace, Environment.StackTrace etc.

Comment: Well, with a try/catch you *promise* "I have all the information needed to handle the exception right here". That includes "knowing" from where it was called, **if needed**. If you don't, then that's a false promise, and it should be handled somewhere higher up, where the promise can be fullfilled. -- or get the full stacktrace another way.

Comment: When exception is thrown, stack is walked up until first exception handler is found. I think there is no reason to explore stack more than this.